# Weird BackgroundWorker issue

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

firstly to my code:

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!this.infoGrabWroker.IsBusy)
        this.infoGrabWroker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void grabInfo()
{
    MessageBox.Show("hi");
}

private void infoGrabWroker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("running");
    this.grabInfo();
    MessageBox.Show("done");
}
```

So now onto the weird part. When i run this it displays the "running" MessageBox, but not the other two MessageBoxes. Now to the even "weirder" part: It works perfectly fine, when i run it with Solution Configuration "Debug", but it does this when i run it in "Release". I haven't messed with the Solution Configuration at all since, i first installed VS2017. Maybe if it's relevant, i haven't done anything to the BackgroundWorker, besides adding the Work event:

```
this.infoGrabWroker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.infoGrabWroker_DoWork);
```

Any ideas why it does this? Thanks in advance and any help is greatly appreciated, since i wasn't able to find any helpful information online.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem and a more precise description of the problem, this question is not answerable. Please don't post questions to Stack Overflow until you have read the introductory information, including the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the other articles about [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I can't describe it better, since i don't know what causes it. My Examination resulted in that the BackgroundWorker goes into the DoWork Event, but then doesn't executes what is called from that event...

Comment: _"I can't describe it better, since i don't know what causes it"_ -- non-sequitur. Not knowing what causes a problem doesn't not interfere with being able to _describe_ the problem better. In the code you posted, one would not expect more than one `MessageBox` to be visible at a time, but your description isn't precise enough to know whether you are confused about how the code executes, or just haven't clearly described the step-by-step operation of the code. In any case, it's not just the description that's lacking. You also need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: See also [ask], including (and especially) the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: @PeterDuniho well i clicked the messagebox after it displayed, so the code could keep on running...